# How to use widgets inside a tkinter frame using grid?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I am using tkinter Frames to  divide the window and I have bound Frames using grid.
Now When I bind the widgets inside a frame using .grid(), it come out of frame automatically and get bound to main tkinter window.
If I use .pack(), it says : _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

myFrame = Frame(root,text="Frame1").grid(row=1,column=1)
MyLabel = Label(myFrame,text="Label inside Frame1").pack()
```

Any other method to bind widgets inside frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a side effect from laying out a widget on the same line as defining it. It causes the widgets to default to root. Try this:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

myFrame = Frame(root,text="Frame1")
myFrame.grid(row=1,column=1)
MyLabel = Label(myFrame,text="Label inside Frame1")
MyLabel.pack()
```